# Constraint layout chains

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Found a case where i find it very hard to use the `ConstraintLayout`
Let me explain the problem i found with the picture attached[image]

Here we have two rows. The green boxes is representing textviews. The orange boxes are representing ImageViews (or any other views in general).

At the first row the Textview1 (left) is constrained to the left side of the screen. The imageview is constrained to this textview.

The problem i have is when this textview is larger than the textview to the right. I do not want to image to clip over that view. I want it to end up like the second row in that image.

I guess that i am suppose to use constraint chains. But i cant manage to get it to work.

Any ideas on how to achieve what i want?

**Edit, Added layout**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv1"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv1"
        tools:background="@drawable/ic_close" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="18 000 000 Dollar" />¨


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please include your layout file contents.

Comment: added one of my tries on this. The left text clips out on the right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ConstrataintLayout` version 1.1.0-beta5 offers some better dimension control that you are looking for. See the [release notes](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/constraintlayoutbeta5isnowavailable).

Specifically, you can make use of `layout_constraintWidth_default = wrap` which will force a `TextView` to wrap once it meets the limits of its constraints.

> Wrap provides a significant new behaviour, with the widget resizing as if wrap_content was used, but limited by the connected constraints. A widget will thus not grow beyond the endpoints.

The following XML places `tv1` and `iv1` in a packed chain constrained by the parent on the left and `tv2` on the right. `tv1` has `app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"` set.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="This is some very long text. How does it behave?"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/iv1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv1"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="#ff9d00"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv1"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="18 000 000 Dollar"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/spacer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tv2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is how things look with this layout with long text...

[image]

... and some short text...

[image]

Comment: This is such a great answer, thank you! The important thing for me here was that I was trying to use `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"` by itself, without `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"`, and my TextView was not aligning to the left. Using both is the key!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `elevation` attribute like z-index in `html`.
add elevation=1dp for ImageView elevation=2dp for TextView like this

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv1"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv1"
    tools:background="@drawable/ic_close" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="18 000 000 Dollar" />¨
```